# MySQL CREATE EVENT wrong syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, events, syntax, mysql-event

**Edit:** I've figured out my MySQL version doesn't support it. I run 5.0.91, it requires 5.1 or so. I'm assuming the syntax is correct. Thanks for the help.

I've just created this mysql event that's supposed to be run every hour. However, I keep getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EVENT event_upcomingbattle ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1
```

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT event_upcomingbattle
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    DO
        CALL update_upcomingbattle();
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Am I missing something stupid? The `update_upcomingbattle()` procedure exists.

Comment: do you have create perms? error is from create bit

Comment: What happens when you change the event name, or put it between `?

Comment: I've figured out my MySQL version doesn't support it. I run 5.0.91, it requires 5.1 or so. I'm assuming the syntax is correct. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL version I was using did not support events. Event support [was added in MySQL 5.1.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html). Instead, I was running 5.0.91. As soon as I updated MySQL, it started working.